# Не работает max-height c padding

Tags: html, css, css3

Задача: сделать блок с соотношением сторон 4:1 (ширина 4, высота 1), и ограничить высоту до 150px, при условии что ширина равна ширине экрана.

```
.some_block{
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 25%;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 150px;
    box-sizing: padding-box;
}
```

Но высота не ограничивается значением max-height; как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

1. У свойства `box-sizing` не может быть значения `padding-box`.
2. `padding-top`, заданный в %, получает этот % от ширины окна браузера. Почему именно так - неизвестно.
3. В вашем условии странная нестыковка: если ограничить высоту 150 пикселами, то максимальная ширина блока - 600px, что приводит к невыполнению пункта `ширина равна ширине экрана` для экранов с большей шириной.
4. Значения высоты в % берутся от высот, а ширины - от широт родительских элементов. Единственный более-менее приличный способ добиться нужного без яваскрипта - привязаться к ширине экрана через vw и ограничить еще и ширину блока (при соотношении сторон 4:1 и `max-height:150px` свойство `max-width:600px` подразумевается). При этом придется учесть, где именно расположен блок и сколько от ширины экрана должна составлять его ширина.

Итого (для примера - блок шириной во весь экран):

```
.some_block {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 25vw;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: 1. Если использовать box-sizing с префиксом,  то значение padding-box может быть.
2. получает процент от ширины блока, если  блок равен ширине браузера.
3,4. Мой недочет, условия неполное, блок  должен быть равен ширине родителя, просто в данном случае это было окно. Ваше решение подходит конкретно под условие, где блок равен ширине экрана (собственно как сказано в описании к вопросу)

Comment: 1. Не может. `box-sizing` может принимать значения `content-box` или `border-box`. Если у вас веб-инспектор не отвергает непредусмотренные спецификацией значения, значит, в нем ошибка. Я сейчас проверил Хром и Файрфокс - Хром не обрабатывает нестандартные значения, ФФ вообще удаляет как ошибочные. С каким именно префиксом у вас получился работающий `padding-box` и  какой эффект это дало?

Comment: 4. Мое решение подходит и под прочие условия, нужно всего лишь произвести примитивный пересчет. Например, если блок должен быть шириной в 30% экрана, то задайте ему `width:30vw; height:calc(25vw * 0.3)`

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
.some_block{
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 25%;

}

.some_block-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    max-height: 150px;
    box-sizing: padding-box;
}

<div class="some_block-wrapper" >
   <div class="some_block" >

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это ничего не решает, .some_block остается слишком высоким.

Comment: @Инквизитор , В данном случае some_block-wrapper удовлетворяет уловие.

Comment: Нет. 
some_block-wrapper не  получает соотношения сторон 4:1. Все, чему он удовлетворяет - это условие `max-height: 150px;`.